# How to position MDIChild form in bottom right corner of MDIParent?

Tags: vb.net, mdichild, mdiparent

Looks like a dumb question, but I tried the following (where "Me" is a MDIParent form):

```
Dim frmNotif As New frmNotifica
With frmNotif
  .MdiParent = Me
  .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
  .Location = New Point(ClientSize.Width - .Width, ClientSize.Height - .Height)
  .Show()
End With
```

but it doesn't work.

Ideas?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an awful diagnostic.  The typical problem here are the fat borders that Aero puts around a window.  For appcompat reasons you get the wrong size of the window.  There's no clean fix for that, adding 4 to the size is a Q&D fix.

Comment: "Doesnt't work" means it is not positioned as intended ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an "empty" MDI Parent form (no Panels or ToolStrips docked), this should work:

```
Dim frmNotif As New frmNotifica
With frmNotif
  .MdiParent = Me
  .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual

  Dim leftStart As Integer = Me.ClientSize.Width - (.Width + (SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width * 2))
  Dim topStart As Integer = Me.ClientSize.Height - (.Height + (SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Height * 2))

  .Location = New Point(leftStart, topStart)
  .Show()
End With
```

If you have a Panel or a ToolStrip added to the MDIParent, you would have to factor that in to your equation, too.

Comment: Two problems: this code needs to run in the form's Load event handler so any auto-rescaling is complete.  And the Border3DSize hack won't work on XP or if Aero is turned off.

Comment: Many thanks! This solves my actual problem. The problem I will have very soon is: what happens if the particular form I want to display in bottom right corner is borderless? Looks like SystemInformation.Border3DSize is the standard size of form's borders for all the system... It seems I'll have to check all the types of forms I want to display there :-)

Comment: @AndreaAntonangeli Do pay attention to Hans Passant's comments.  This solution *may* not work in all circumstances.  If positioning of child forms is critical to the application, MDI may not be the best way to approach it.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your comment: I'll take it in consideration, since some clients may have XP. Funny how such a simple thing can become complex ...

Comment: Just checked with a bordeless form and it is still OK.